# jQuery .on('click') duplicate ajax calls

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a problem with duplicate ajax calls in my app.
Here is my jQuery code:

```
$(document.body).on('click', 'a.sample', function(event) {
   event.preventDefault();

   $('#UniqueFormId').submit(function(event) {
      event.preventDefault();

      // HERE IS AJAX CALL //

      return false;
   });
});
```

The problem appears when I click a few times on `a.sample` button without submit a `#UniqueFormId` form. And next click button with submit form make duplicate ajax calls.

I use `$(document.body)` because I wont use it globaly after ajax calls.
How I can avoid duplicate ajax calls?

Comment: Try, $(document.body).off('click').on('click',

Comment: Thanks, Yours answers was very helpful. But, I can't use `$('#UniqueFormId').submit();` like write @Manchary, @Zakaria, @Matthew after click event on `a.sample`. Because `a.sample` click shows bootstrap modal wher I put a form `#UniqueFormId`.

I have to wait for user submit this form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could disable the button after click event then enable it after `success/error` callback of ajax request :

```
$('#UniqueFormId').submit(function(event) {
      event.preventDefault();

      var _this = $(this);
      _this.attr('disabled', 'disabled'); //disable the button

      // IN AJAX CALLBACK
      _this.removeAttr('disabled'); //enable the button again

      return false;
});

$(document.body).on('click', 'a.sample', function(event) {
   event.preventDefault();

   //Load your Modal here
});
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: You don't have to use `$('#UniqueFormId').submit();` just open you modal instead and separate submit function from `a.sample` click event

Answer (score 1):

You can `1` use a simple flag that doesn't rely on any DOM interaction, and then also `2` refactor the submit handler to be set outside of the click event. You just want the click event to fire the ajax submit, not set the handler.

In this case, `is_sending` will force the submit function to back off if it is set to true. You can see that this is set in the `beforeSend` callback, and cleared in the `complete` callback (called on both success and error, so it will always allow a retry. Mod this to your liking...)

Hope this helps and makes sense! This pattern should ensure that only one ajax request is active at any given time for this particular form.

```
var is_sending = false; // Default to false, then set to true when ajax request starts...

$(document.body).on('click', 'a.sample', function(event) {
   event.preventDefault();
   $('#UniqueFormId').submit();
});

$('#UniqueFormId').submit(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    if (is_sending) return false;
    $.ajax({
      ...
      beforeSend: function () {
        is_sending = true;
      },
      complete: function () {
        is_sending = false;
      },
      success: function (response) {
        // Do whatever...
      }
    });
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

Just separate your `submit()` and `click()` functions

```
$('#UniqueFormId').submit(function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();

       // HERE IS AJAX CALL //

       return false;
   });

$(document.body).on('click', 'a.sample', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
   $('#UniqueFormId').submit();
 });
```